# ASIHTTPRequest and ShareKit in the same app has two reachability files

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, sharekit, reachability

I am creating an iOS app which uses both ASIHTTPRequest and ShareKit. Both APIs have a Reachability.h and Reachability.m file... thus this is creating a Mach-O duplication error. Is there a special way to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: People will be more inclined to help you if you start marking your answers.  You have several questions, but not one accepted answer.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize I was suppose to do that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue a little while back and figured out an easy fix.

You have two options.

1) If the versions of the two Reachability sets are the same, you could just delete one set. I don't think you should even have to change any headers.

2) If the versions are different, rename one set of Reachability files something like "MyReachability". Obviously you will have to clean up all references to the renamed class as well.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Have you ever tried the second way? I can't seem to get it working and I've checked many times

Comment: I tried both of those and they don't seem to work... Which way did you go about it?

Comment: I used the second way, and had no problem. What you might want to do is create a project with just ASIHTTPRequest OR just ShareKit. Build so you know that every thing is okay, and then rename the Reachability classes. Test it again, and assuming everything is okay transfer it to your real project.